# Vba Excel make a button visible in userform as long as multiple key are pressed

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm programming a small userform with multiple buttons, listboxes.
There is a button called "Delete" that i want to hide, because data should be deleted only in very rare cases.
The button should be only visible when i press certain keys on the keyboard. e.g. ctr + "e" oder ctr +"k".
When this keys are not pressed the button should be hidden again
I tried to use the event keydown of the userform but in vain.
can you help me please with this one ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `The button should be only visible when i press certain keys on the keyboard. e.g. ctr + "e"` This can be done. `When this keys are not pressed the button should be hidden again` This doesn't make sense to me. Because to use the button, one will have to let go of the ctrl key. I would recommend a second set of keys to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to catch this would probably be to use the `KeyPress` and `KeyUp` events in the userform.

Something as simple as:

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If KeyAscii = 11 Or KeyAscii = 5 Then Me.Delete.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Me.Delete.Visible = False
End Sub
```

In the userform code.
And the `KeyAscii` set to whatever value you need, 11 being ctrl + k, 5 being ctrl + e.

Using KeyDown should work in a similar manner, but KeyCode and KeyAscii are different:

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 75 Then Me.Delete.Visible = True
End Sub
```

And then finally, for a toggle function:

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 75 And Not Me.Delete.Visible Then
    Me.Delete.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Delete.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Using `UserForm_` subs only triggers the code if the useform in question is in focus. If other userforms are in focus, then they would have to call the code, and if no useform is in focus, you can call a sub from a module with a shortcut from the macro menu. The same code, using the specific name rather than `Me` works for wherever you cal lthe code from.

Comment: Instead of keyup (that will just hide the button as soon as they release ctl+K and won't be able to use it), I would make a toggle in the keypress that checks if the button is visible or not. That way each press of ctl+k will either hide or unhide the button.

Comment: @Simon You will be able to use it, just hold ctrl + k and then click it with the mouse. I agree that it isn't a great design, but it is what was requested.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I believe the `UserForm_KeyPress()` (or any of the other events) wont fire if any other control on the form has the focus. Have you tried it?

Comment: @KostasK. It will not, no. If that's a problem, you could add it to all the userforms. Obivosuly using the name of the form, rather than `Me`

Comment: You will have ti use APIs to achieve what OP wants.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Why? To be able to show the key when no userform is focused? Just use a macro with a shortcut or `Application.OnKey`?

Comment: @chritofer thanks for you answer I'll test it an come back to you. Many Thanks

Comment: Because if there are multiple controls and they are active; say a textbox then your code will not work :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout That's true. I guess you can put the code in all the controls as well, like `TextBox1_KeyDown`, but yeah, it might get a bit messy.

Comment: And hence I suggested API which doesn't depend on the any other controls in the userform :)

Answer (score 1):

> When this keys are not pressed the button should be hidden again

This doesn't make sense to me. Because to use the button, one will have to let go of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key. I would recommend a second set of keys to hide it. Or better still... **Use the same key!!!** :)

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal id As Long, _
ByVal fsModifiers As Long, ByVal vk As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal id As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" _
Alias "PeekMessageA" (lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, _
ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long
   
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type MSG
    hwnd As LongPtr
    message As Long
    wParam As LongPtr
    lParam As LongPtr
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type

Private Const MOD_CONTROL = &H2
Private Const PM_REMOVE = &H1
Private Const WM_HOTKEY = &H312
Private CancelTrap As Boolean
Private ShowHide As Boolean

Private Const ShowHideKey As Long = vbKeyE

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    CaptureShowHideKey True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    CaptureShowHideKey False
End Sub

Private Sub CaptureShowHideKey(Trap As Boolean)
    CancelTrap = Not Trap
    If Trap = True Then
        Call RegisterHotKey(0, &HBFFF&, MOD_CONTROL, ShowHideKey)
        ShowHideButton
    Else
        Call UnregisterHotKey(0, &HBFFF&)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowHideButton()
    Dim message As MSG
    
    Do While Not CancelTrap
        WaitMessage
        If PeekMessage(message, 0, WM_HOTKEY, WM_HOTKEY, PM_REMOVE) Then
            If CommandButton1.Visible = False Then
                CommandButton1.Visible = True
            Else
                CommandButton1.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

**IN ACTION**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Siddharth for you help. the reason behind making the button disappear automatically when whe buttons Ctr +E are not down is to avoid the users deleting data. the only user that knows this "code" can unhinde the button an delete what he wants. I'll test your solution and come back to you. thanks for your efforts (flower)

Comment: hi @siddharth , can you please adjust the code to hide the button as soon as you stop pressing Ctr +E ? . the code is almost perfect for me. many many thanks in advance